# How to std::vector resize assigning default value

Tags: c++, vector

I have `std::vector<bool> v`
I want to resize it and put false value to all its elements. How can I do it efficiently (without loop)
How can I do it?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize. Do you want to set all the elements or only the new ones?

Comment: @BessieTheCow - all . (v is empty)

Comment: Just use the second overload in the page I linked to or pass the number of elements and the value to the constructor.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is specialized to be packed for space efficiency.  But it has some quirks in behavior if one expects the general behavior of std::vector.  If you really need non-specialized behavior consider `enum class bool_t: bool { false_v, true_v };` and `std::vector<bool_t>`.  (Too bad they didn't have `std::vector_bool` that has the packed behavior.  Alas, that ship has sailed.)

Answer (score 3):

If `v` has already been constructed, you can use `assign` method to achieve your goal.

```
v.assign(count, false);
```

**NOTE**: `vector<bool>` might be space-efficient optimized, and behaves different than other types of `vector`, e.g. the underlying storage might not be contiguous. And you might want to replace it with `vector<int>` or `bitset<N>`. You can check the [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) for detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    vector<bool> v(5,true);
    
    cout << "Initial size  = " << v.size() << endl;
    
    /* displaying Initial vector values */
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
       cout << v[i] << " ";
    cout<<endl;
    
    /* 
        Resize it to required length
        Parameters:

        1st argument – it is a new container size, expressed in a number of elements.
        2nd argument – if this parameter is specified then new elements are 
                       initialized with this value.
    */  
    
    v.resize(10,false);
    
    cout << "Size after resize = " << v.size() << endl;
    
    /* displaying current vector values */
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
       cout << v[i] << " ";
    cout<<endl;
    
    
    /* 
        assign new values to the vector
        1. length upto which new values are to be assigned
        2. value to be assign
    */
    v.assign(v.size(),false);

    cout << "size after assign = " << v.size() << endl;
    
    /* display modified vector values */
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
       cout << v[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Ouput:

```
Initial size  = 5
1 1 1 1 1 
Size after resize = 10
1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
size after assign = 10
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Don't do `int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i`. Firstly, you have type signed-ness mismatch: `int` is signed, `v.size()` is unsigned, secondly, on 64bit machine you'll likely have size mismatch, `int` is typically 32 bits, `v.size()` is 64 bits.